# Static file hosting limits on App Engine with Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, limits

I've been trying to find documentation on static file hosting with App Engine and Go for a while now, but can't find anything current in the documentation.

I've found a number of (unofficial) references from about 5 years ago to a 10,000 file limit with a max of 1,000 per directory, but I haven't been able to find any current official documentation on this other than information on billing for static files.

**So what are the static file hosting limits on App Engine** (using Go if that changes things)?  Any links to official documentation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently on the Quotas documentation, under [Deployment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments):

> The number of times the application has been uploaded by a developer. The current quota is 10,000 per day.
>
> An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. Additionally, if the total size of all files for all versions exceeds the initial free 1 gigabyte, then there will be a $ 0.026 per GB per month charge.

Comment: Thanks Jaime.  Do you know if it's possible to have this increased in the way that many of the other quotas can be increased for paid apps on request?

Comment: Honestly I don't think that you can (without a Premier account); I think the idea is that at that point you should consider implementing a custom solution for your special needs, in this case setting up your own CDN.